# Android GPS based app satellite icon does not show

Tags: android, gps, icons, satellite

I made a GPS based app, which works perfectly except for a little mistake.
I use TABs on the main screen. Before I use TABs the satellite icon shown when the GPS/LocationListener/ is working. After I redesign the GUI with TabHost/TabView and never show the satellite icon on the top of the screen, the battery state and time does not show too. Only the application title show.
My question is what need I do for show satellite icon when the GPS is working?

Comment: Show us your AndroidManifest.xml and styles.xml

Comment: The style is empty
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="GTLThemes" parent="android:Theme" />
</resources>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN` and `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE` flags usage in your tab activity. I think you've set them.